# How can i navigate to another page without popping the drawer in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, drawer

I want to transition between pages while having the drawer **on top of everything** so that the page changes and the drawer doesn't pop, it **must always stay on top of everything** unless I want to hide it.

Answer (score -1):

Use state managers like Redux, Bloc, Provider.

Create a separate widget for the drawer and just use in anywhere you need to.

Example: Manage the Drawer State with a [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)

Controller

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MenuController extends ChangeNotifier {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> get scaffoldKey => _scaffoldKey;

  void controlMenu() {
    if (!_scaffoldKey.currentState!.isDrawerOpen) {
      _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();
    }
  }
}
```

Adding State Management to the Widget tree

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: bgColor,
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(Theme.of(context).textTheme)
            .apply(bodyColor: Colors.white),
        canvasColor: secondaryColor,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (context) => MenuController(),
          ),
        ],
        child: HomeScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Creating The Drawer Widget

```
class SideMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  const SideMenu({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          DrawerHeader(
            child: Image.asset("assets/images/logo.png"),
          ),
          DrawerListTile(
            title: "Dashboard",
            svgSrc: "assets/icons/menu_dashbord.svg",
            press: () {},
          ),
          DrawerListTile(
            title: "Pages",
            svgSrc: "assets/icons/page.svg",
            press: () {},
          ),
          DrawerListTile(
            title: "Applications",
            svgSrc: "assets/icons/application.svg",
            press: () {},
          ),
          DrawerListTile(
            title: "UI Components",
            svgSrc: "assets/icons/ui.svg",
            press: () {},
          ),
          DrawerListTile(
            title: "Widgets",
            svgSrc: "assets/icons/widget.svg",
            press: () {},
          ),
          DrawerListTile(
            title: "Forms",
            svgSrc: "assets/icons/forms.svg",
            press: () {},
          ),
          DrawerListTile(
            title: "Charts",
            svgSrc: "assets/icons/chart.svg",
            press: () {},
          ),
          DrawerListTile(
            title: "Settings",
            svgSrc: "assets/icons/menu_setting.svg",
            press: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DrawerListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const DrawerListTile({
    Key? key,
    // For selecting those three line once press "Command+D"
    required this.title,
    required this.svgSrc,
    required this.press,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String title, svgSrc;
  final VoidCallback press;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      onTap: press,
      horizontalTitleGap: 0.0,
      leading: SvgPicture.asset(
        svgSrc,
        color: primaryColor,
        height: 16,
      ),
      title: Text(
        title,
        style: TextStyle(color: primaryColor),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Use of Drawer in your pages

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<MyAboutPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: context.read<MenuController>().scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('About Page'),
      ),
      drawer: SideMenu(),
    );
  }
}
```

Control state if you want to open drawer on click

```
IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
              onPressed: context.read<MenuController>().controlMenu,
            ),
```

Comment: for a new flutter user this seems very complicated, thanks for the info but i understood almost nothing